# Prolog - how to print a list

Tags: prolog

I need to print list elements but I'm having troubles...
I have facts like these:

```
processor('Intel Core i3 8100', 104, 'low_range')   .
processor('Ryzen 5 2400g', 135, 'middle_range').    
motherboard('Gigabyte Z370P D3', 98, 'low_range')   .
motherboard('Gigabyte GBT AX370M-DS3H', 70, 'middle_range').
.....
configuration(P, M, R, C, A, V, S, D, H, Price_range) :-
    processor(P, _Proc_price, Price_range),
    motherboard(M, _Motherboard_price, Price_range),
    ram(R, _Ram_price, Price_range),
    case(C, _Case_price, Price_range),
    ali(A, _Ali_price, Price_range),
    video_card(V, _Vga_price, Price_range),
    ssd(S, _Ssd_price, Price_range),
    monitor(D, _Monitor_price, Price_range),
    hdd(H, _Hdd_price, Price_range).
```

I filter these configurations by findall function:

```
findall(P-M-R-C-A-V-S-D-H, configuration(P, M, R, C, A, V, S, D, H, T), Res),
```

I need to print Res elements in that way:

```
configuration number 1
processor
motherboard
ram
case
ali
video card
ssd
monitor
hdd

configuration number 2
processor
motherboard
ram
case
ali
video card
ssd
monitor
hdd

....

configuration number N
processor
motherboard
ram
case
ali
video card
ssd
monitor
hdd
```

Could you help me please? I'm not understanding how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `forall/2` instead of `findall/3`:

> `forall(:Cond, :Action)`
>   For all alternative bindings of *Cond*, *Action* can be proven.

e.g.:

```
forall(configuration(P, M, R, C, A, V, S, D, H, T),
    (writeln(configuration), writeln(P), writeln(M), ...)).
```

Edit: you can make a counter in this way:

```
:- dynamic(mycounter/1).
:- assertz(mycounter(0)).

incr_mycounter(X):-
    mycounter(X),
    retractall(mycounter(_)),
    succ(X,Y),
    assertz(mycounter(Y)).
```

and use it like this:

```
forall(configuration(P, M, R, C, A, V, S, D, H, T),
    (incr_mycounter(N), writeln(configuration-N), writeln(P), writeln(M), ...)).
```

Comment: You are my hero!!! I've just one problem with this, I'm trying to print a message like "configuration numer n" before each configuration, I've put this before forall: I = 1, Q = 'Configuration number ', I've put this at forall start: string_concat(Q, I, N_conf) and it works, but if I put I = I+1 at forall end I got error before printing second configuration! why?